# Find the longest rainless time (every hour, beyond several days)

Tags: sql, date, datetime, gaps-and-islands, mariadb-10.1

I have a *weather station* where I measure the amount of rain per hour and save the data in a database. The rain-table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Rain` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rain` double NOT NULL,
  `date_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `Rain` (`id`, `rain`, `date_time`) VALUES
(1, 0, '2020-07-12 21:00:01'),
(2, 0, '2020-07-12 22:00:01'),
(3, 0, '2020-07-12 23:00:01'),
(4, 0, '2020-07-13 00:00:01'),
(5, 0, '2020-07-13 01:00:01'),
(6, 0, '2020-07-13 02:00:01'),
(7, 0, '2020-07-13 03:00:01');
```

Now I want the *longest rainless* time per month. I already have a solution, but it only works for the respective day. However, if there is no rain for several days, my solution will not work correctly...

#### My current statement looks like this:

```
SET @row_number:=0;
SELECT rain, date_time, 
        EXTRACT(DAY_HOUR FROM date_time) - @row_number:=@row_number+1 as 'check_sum'
FROM Rain 
WHERE rain=(SELECT MIN(rain) 
            FROM Rain 
            WHERE date_time BETWEEN '2020-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-31 00:00:00'
            ) 
AND date_time BETWEEN '2020-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-31 00:00:00'
```

#### The output from this statement is as follow:

```
rain date_time           check_sum
   0 2020-07-12 21:00:01      1220
   0 2020-07-12 22:00:02      1220
   0 2020-07-12 23:00:01      1220 
   0 2020-07-13 00:00:01      1296
   0 2020-07-13 01:00:01      1296
   0 2020-07-13 02:00:01      1296
   0 2020-07-13 03:00:01      1296
   0 2020-07-13 04:00:01      1296
   0 2020-07-13 04:00:01      1296
```

Although it **didn't rain**, I get a **different `checksum`** for the following day.

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/67120a/2)

I also know why, but I don't know how I can solve it differently in order to achieve what I intend to do.

```
day/hour       @row_number+1
(12/21) 1221 -       1       = 1220 same
(12/22) 1222 -       2       = 1220 same
(12/23) 1223 -       3       = 1220 same
(13/00) 1300 -       4       = 1296 not same (day changed)
(13/01) 1301 -       5       = 1296 not same (day changed)
(13/02) 1302 -       6       = 1296 not same (day changed)
```

Does anyone know how to do it despite the change of day and the *same `check sum`*? Or is there another way (completely new approach/new query) to solve my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks, I have add a SQLFIDDLE-Link

Comment: The data set isn't representative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In older versions, you can use variables:

```
SELECT MIN(date_time), MAX(date_time),
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour, MIN(date_time), MAX(date_time)) hours
FROM (SELECT r.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
      FROM (SELECT r.*, FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time) / 3600) as hh
            FROM Rain r
            WHERE rain = 0
            ORDER BY date_time
           ) r CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rn := 0) params
      ) r
GROUP BY (hh - rn)
ORDER BY hours desc
```

Add `LIMIT 1` to get the top number of hours.

The idea is to calculate the number of hours (since the beginning of time) for each rainless day.  If you subtract a sequential number from the number of hours, you get a constant for hours that are in sequence.

Note that this approach also works with window functions as well:

```
SELECT MIN(date_time), MAX(date_time),
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour, MIN(date_time), MAX(date_time)) hours
FROM (SELECT r.*, FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time) / 3600) as hh,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date_time) as rn
      FROM Rain r
      WHERE rain = 0
     ) r
GROUP BY (hh - rn)
ORDER BY hours desc
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for this solution and the well explaining!! But for what is the under approach (`...also works with window function as well`) ??

Comment: @SwissCodeMen . . . I just wanted to point out that you can generate the sequence using window functions.  Until you upgrade your database, that is not relevant -- but it might help someone else who stumbles on the question.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a gaps-and-islands problem to me. I understand that you want the longest streak of `0`s in column `rain`.

If you are running MySQL 8.0, an approach is to use the difference between row numbers:

```
select 
    min(date_time) start_date_time, 
    max(date_time) end_date_time, 
    count(*) no_hours
from (
    select 
        r.*,
        row_number() over(order by date_time) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by rain order by date_time) rn2
    from rain r
) r
where rain = 0
group by rn1 - rn2
order by no_hours desc
```

Comment: My server version is: 10.1.38-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 - Raspbian 9.0. And it gives my an error: `check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(order by date_time) rn1, row_number() over(partition by rain order by d' at line 8`